# EF Core to use NUGET Package Manager Console or CMD

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add initial migration  using EF Core. I am not sure which one to use OR when I should be using the below. I am using EF core 1.1

`dotnet ef migration add init` (using window console)

OR

`add-migration init` (using Nuget Console)

I have been using Nuget Package Manager Console in the past (EF 6) for migration.

I also noticed that both are being used for EF Core but I am not sure for which .NET framework (.NET Core) version the above commands are valid.

regards,
Alan

Comment: you can use any

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As [Martin said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41932566/475031), you can use either. The `dotnet ef` command even works in PMC if you `cd` to the project first. There is even a third command: `ef.exe` that can be found in the NuGet package.

Here is an explanation of what each one gives you: (in "ascending" order)

- **ef.exe**--Operates on raw assemblies. You tell it project info.
- **dotnet ef**--Operates on `*.csproj` files (using MSBuild). Infers project info. Calls `ef.exe`
- **PMC Tools**--Operates on Visual Studio projects (using EnvDTE). Infers project info. Detects the startup project. Opens files in the IDE. Has tab-expansion for command arguments. Calls `ef.exe`

So, to get the best experience, use the PMC Tools (i.e. `Add-Migration`, etc.) if you can.

Answer (score 2):

You can use either.

Personally, I like to use the NuGet console, as I dont have to leave Visual Studio. The PowerShell commands from NuGet console simple run the dotnet.exe commands under the hood anyway - They are just syntactic sugar :)